# Variables are not rendering

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I’m making a blog site. And I have been trying to render from a model, RecentPosts, objects rpost1, etc. in my template blogs -file *base.html* which is my blog's details page.

But it is not rendering. Is there a solution?

#### File *views.py*

```python
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from blog.models import  Post
from django.contrib import messages
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from .models import Post, RecentPosts, Comment, Contact, Populars
from datetime import datetime
from .forms import CommentForm

def index(request):
  return render(request, 'index.html')

def path(request):
  return render(request, 'blog.html')

def cv(request):
  return render(request, 'cv.html')

class HomeView(ListView):
  model = Post
  template_name = 'listview.html'

class ArticleDetailView(DetailView):
  model = Post
  template_name = 'base2.html'

def rpost(request):
  template_name = "blogs-base.html"
  rpost = RecentPosts.objects.all()
  context =  {'rpost': 'rpost'}
  return render(request, template_name, context)
```

---

This is the URL portion.

#### File *urls.py*

```python
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from .views import HomeView, ArticleDetailView, contact, Comment_page, popular

urlpatterns = [

  path('', views.index, name='index'),
  path('index.html', views.index, name='index'),
  path('cv.html', views.cv, name='cv'),
  path('blogs/', views.HomeView.as_view(), name="blogs"),
  path('blogs/<slug:slug>', ArticleDetailView.as_view(), name='base2'),
  path('contact/', views.contact, name='contact'),
  path('contact.html/', views.contact, name='contact'),
  path('comment.html/', views.Comment_page, name='comment'),
  path('popular', views.popular, name='popular'),
]
```

---

This is the model portion.

#### File *models.py*

```python
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse
from django.utils.timezone import now

# Create your models here.
class Post(models.Model):

  title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
  author_name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
  author_description = models.CharField(max_length=120)
  body = models.TextField(default='')
  slug = models.CharField(max_length = 130)

  timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

  def get_abosolute_url(self):
    return reverse()

class Comment(models.Model):

  post = models.ForeignKey('Post', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
  user = models.CharField(max_length=200)

  message = models.TextField()
  timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

  def __str__(self):
    return self.user.capitalize() + ' : ' + self.message[0:16] + '........'

class Contact(models.Model):

  email = models.CharField(max_length=20)
  message = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  models.CharField(max_length=200)

class RecentPosts(models.Model):

  rpost1 = models.CharField(max_length=120)
  rpost2 = models.CharField(max_length=120)
  rpost3 = models.CharField(max_length=120
)
```

---

#### File *blogs-base.html*

```html
<a href="marketing-single.html" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action flex-column align-items-start">
<div class="w-100 justify-content-between">
  <img src="assets/blog-uploads/ad.png" alt="" class="img-fluid float-left">
  {% for i in rpost %} <h5 class="mb1">{{i.rpost1}}</h5>
  <small>12 Jan, 2016</small>{% endfor %}
</div>
</a>
```

---

This is the listview where I’m posting only my blog's thumbnails.

#### File *listview.html*

```html
{% extends 'blogs-base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block title %}{{post.title}}{%  endblock %}
{% block content %}

{% for post in object_list %}
<div class="col-lg-6">
  <div class="blog-box">
    <div class="post-media">
      <a href="marketing-single.html" title="">
      <img src="{% static 'website/assets/blog-uploads/ad.png' %}" alt="" class="img-fluid">
      <div class="hovereffect">
        <span class=""></span>
      </div><!-- end hover -->
      </a>
    </div><!-- end media -->

    <div class="blog-meta">
      <h4><a href="{% url 'base2' post.slug  %}" title="" style="color: white;">{{post.title}}</a></h4>
      <small><a href="{% url 'base2' post.slug  %}" title="" style="color: white;"></a></small>
      <small><a href="{% url 'base2' post.slug  %}" title="" style="color: white;">20 July, 2017</a></small><br><br>
    </div><!-- end meta -->

  </div><!-- end blog-box -->
</div><!-- end col -->
{% endfor %}
{%  endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You made a mistake in your context. You're are passing a string of 'rpost' instead of

```
context = { "rpost" : rpost }
```